# Nexus S: NoClassDefFoundError when using NFC

Tags: android, nfc

I'm trying to develop a small application which uses NFC on the Nexus S. Every time when I try to start my app on the phone (via Eclipse), it gives me an error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.nfc.tech.IsoDep
```

I tried the "API Demos" which comes with the SDK, but even this app gives me the error when starting the NFC part... All other functionalities are working fine. 
Does anyone has some hints for me?? I'm using Android 2.4.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to set permissions in the android manifest file.  I don't have access to my development tools to try this right now, but something like:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" />
```

See http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NFCDemo/index.html

Comment: Possibly also: <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />

Comment: Hi,thanks for your answer, but I have set the permissions correctly... The problem is, that I don't think the project is configured wrong  because it gives me the NoClassDefFoundError, but I can't imagine what the problem is.....??

Comment: Please post your source code and maybe we can find a problem with that?

Comment: I don't have a nexus s to tell you where to look, but are you sure that the NFC features / hardware is enabled?  Probably under system settings.  From your app it looks like you could do NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()!=null and isEnabled() to verify that hardware is present (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html)